# merging multiple data sets with similar columns names

Tags: pandas, dataset

I have a multiple data sets represents multiple economic indicators. 
Every data set have 5 columns with the same columns names for every data set.
The columns names are [Date Time, Actual, Consensus, Previous, Revised].
The thing is I want to merge these data sets into a single one to prepare it for future work.
I did try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Tutorial\Sentix Investor Confidence - European Monetary Union.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Tutorial\Services Sentiment - European Monetary Union.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Tutorial\ZEW Survey - Economic Sentiment - European Monetary Union.csv')
frames = [df1, df2, df3]
result = pd.concat(frames,join='inner')
print(result)
```

But the result is like this
[data result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W6ci.jpg)
Which is absolutely wrong for me because despite similarity in names it’s extremely different indictors so I can NOT just mix them together.
What I need is some thing [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhYkX.jpg), 
or some other thing do similar job to remain every indictor with its identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still using `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df,df,df],keys=['yourkey1','yourkey2','yourkey3'],axis=1)
Out[234]: 
  yourkey1     yourkey2     yourkey3    
        C1  C2       C1  C2       C1  C2
0        1  10        1  10        1  10
1        2  20        2  20        2  20
2        3   3        3   3        3   3
3        4  40        4  40        4  40
```

Data input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [1,2,3,'4'], 'C2': [10, 20, '3',40]})
```

change the 'yourkey_' to the one you need